# WPF - Zooming in on an image inside a scroll viewer, and having the scrollbars adjust accordingly

Tags: wpf, image-processing

I have put together a simple WPF application to demonstrate the issue I am having. My XAML is below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="427" Width="467" Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="MyScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="True">
            <Image Name="MyImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseWheel="UIElement_OnMouseWheel" MouseDown="MyImage_OnMouseDown" MouseUp="MyImage_OnMouseUp"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind is below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UIElement_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            var matrix = MyImage.RenderTransform.Value;

            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                matrix.ScaleAt(1.5, 1.5, e.GetPosition(this).X, e.GetPosition(this).Y);
            }
            else
            {
                matrix.ScaleAt(1.0 / 1.5, 1.0 / 1.5, e.GetPosition(this).X, e.GetPosition(this).Y);
            }

            MyImage.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
        }

        private WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap;

        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var image = new WriteableBitmap(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\myImage.png", UriKind.Absolute)));

            MyImage.Width = image.Width;
            MyImage.Height = image.Height;

            image = BitmapFactory.ConvertToPbgra32Format(image);

            writeableBitmap = image;

            MyImage.Source = image;
        }

        private Point downPoint;
        private Point upPoint;

        private void MyImage_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            downPoint = e.GetPosition(MyImage);
        }

        private void MyImage_OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            upPoint = e.GetPosition(MyImage);

            writeableBitmap.DrawRectangle(Convert.ToInt32(downPoint.X), Convert.ToInt32(downPoint.Y), Convert.ToInt32(upPoint.X), Convert.ToInt32(upPoint.Y), Colors.Red);
            MyImage.Source = writeableBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added WriteableBitmapEx using Nuget. If you run this, and replace **myImage.png** with the location of an actual image on your computer, you will find an application that looks something like this:

[image: App]

You can draw a box on the image by clicking on the top-left of where you want the box to go and dragging to the bottom right of where you want the box to go, you get a red rectangle. You can even zoom in with the middle-mouse, and draw a rectangle up close for more precision, this works as expected.

The problem is that, when you scroll in with the middle mouse, the scroll bars don't re-adjust, which is a requirement of the program I am creating. My question is how do I force the scrollbars on the scrollviewer to re-adjust when the image is zoomed in?

I am convinced it has something to do with the RenderTransform property of the ScrollViewer, and that I need to update it at the same time I update the RenderTransform property of the image (on UIElement_OnMouseWheel) but I am unsure of exactly how to go about this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be using `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform` on your Image.

`RenderTransform` happens after layout completes and is visual only. `LayoutTransform` is done before the layout pass and so can notify the `ScrollViewer` of the new size.

See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx

Answer (score 9):

For pure scrolling I'd rather use a ScaleTransform, it should adjust the scrollbars accordingly.
You can try below code if it fixes your issue.

```
private double _zoomValue = 1.0;

private void UIElement_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Delta > 0)
  {
    _zoomValue += 0.1;
  }
  else
  {
    _zoomValue -= 0.1;
  }

  ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(_zoomValue, _zoomValue);
  MyImage.LayoutTransform = scale;
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Let's assume you have a Canvas_Main inside a ViewBox_CanvasMain, which in turn inside a ScrollViewer_CanvasMain. You want to zoom in by turning the mouse wheel,  and the ScrollViewer will adjust the offset automatically so the feature (pointed by the mouse in the Canvas_Main) stays during the zoom in/out. It is complex but here is the code called by the mouse wheel eventhandler:

```
    private void MouseWheelZoom(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Canvas_Main.IsMouseOver)
        {

            Point mouseAtImage = e.GetPosition(Canvas_Main); // ScrollViewer_CanvasMain.TranslatePoint(middleOfScrollViewer, Canvas_Main);
            Point mouseAtScrollViewer = e.GetPosition(ScrollViewer_CanvasMain);

            ScaleTransform st = ViewBox_CanvasMain.LayoutTransform as ScaleTransform;
            if (st == null)
            {
                st = new ScaleTransform();
                ViewBox_CanvasMain.LayoutTransform = st;
            }

            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                st.ScaleX = st.ScaleY = st.ScaleX * 1.25;
                if (st.ScaleX > 64) st.ScaleX = st.ScaleY = 64;
            }
            else
            {
                st.ScaleX = st.ScaleY = st.ScaleX / 1.25;
                if (st.ScaleX < 1) st.ScaleX = st.ScaleY = 1;
            }
            #region [this step is critical for offset]
            ScrollViewer_CanvasMain.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(0);
            ScrollViewer_CanvasMain.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
            this.UpdateLayout();
            #endregion

            Vector offset = Canvas_Main.TranslatePoint(mouseAtImage, ScrollViewer_CanvasMain) - mouseAtScrollViewer; // (Vector)middleOfScrollViewer;
            ScrollViewer_CanvasMain.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset.X);
            ScrollViewer_CanvasMain.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset.Y);
            this.UpdateLayout();

            e.Handled = true;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Note ViewBox is a "Grid" control not a "ViewBox".