# How to Draw on Zoomable Image in C# windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, zooming, line

so am implementing a project that can read image pan it, zoom it and do other stuff.. everything was going well until i tried implementing a draw with right mouse button.

the problem is when i draw a line, the line that appears on the image does not correspond to the line i drew on screen, meaning its shifted and i know its because of the re-sizing and zooming of the image, but when i draw lines on the image with its original size(the image) and with panning also ; i have no problem.

here's the code.

so first here is how i load the image when i click browse and select image

```
Myimage = new Bitmap(ImagePath);
resized = myImage.Size;
imageResize();
pictureBox.Paint += new    System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox_Paint);
                pictureBox.Invalidate();
```

the imageResize function does the following:

```
void imageResize()
{     
//calculated the size to fit the control i will draw the image on   
 resized.Height = someMath;
 resized.Width = someMath;
}
```

then in the event handler for the pictureBox_Paint event i wrote:

```
private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender,      System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
// Create a local version of the graphics object for the PictureBox.
Graphics PboxGraphics = e.Graphics;
PboxGraphics.DrawImage(myImage, imageULcorner.X, imageULcorner.Y,     resized.Width, resized.Height);
}
```

as you can see the resized size is not the original image size i did this because i wanted the image to show on the picturebox control centralized and filled now the next part IS WHERE MY PROBLEM BEGINS

i have to draw lines on image using right mouse button so i implemented pictureBox_MouseDown & pictureBox_MouseUp event handlers

```
// mouse down event handler
private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
else if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
mouseDown = mouse.Location;
mouseDown.X = mouseDown.X - imageULcorner.X;
mouseDown.Y = mouseDown.Y - imageULcorner.Y;
draw = true;
}
}
```

here is the mouse up event handler

```
//Mouse UP
private void pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
else if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
{
if (draw)
 {
mouseLocationNow.X = mouse.X - imageULcorner.X;
mouseLocationNow.Y = mouse.Y - imageULcorner.Y;
//
// get graphics object of the image ( the original not the resized)
// as the resized image only appears when i draw on the graphics of the
// pictureBox control
// i know the problem lies here but how can i fix it
//
Graphics image = Graphics.FromImage(myImage);
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
image.DrawLine(pen, mouseLocationNow, mouseDown);
pictureBox.Invalidate();
}
draw = false;
}
```

so in the end i want to be able to draw on the re-sized image and make it correspond to the real image and also to the screen where i draw the line 
thanks and sorry for the long post but this problem has been driving me crazy.

Comment: The short version is: you need to a) calculate the points from the mouse event to fit to the zoom (backward since you are aiming at the zoomed world) and b) scale the graphics object (forward, using a Matrix transformation) to the same zoom as the image in the picturebox.

Comment: If you're willing to use WPF, I have asked a similar question in the past. The question and answer may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729853/wpf-zooming-in-on-an-image-inside-a-scroll-viewer-and-having-the-scrollbars-a

Comment: @TaW i was aware of (A) but i didnt know (B) existed... sounds like a good track to find a solution .. thanks.

Comment: Using a `Matrix` to accomplish the zooming (which is a good idea), then you can get the inverse matrix also and use that to transform the user input mouse coordinates back to the coordinate space of your image. Basically, you wind up doing all of the real work in the original image coordinate space, using the matrices to convert user input back to the image coordinate space, and to convert from the image coordinate space (i.e. the image itself and any other rendering on top of it, such as a selection rect) back to the screen during the `Paint` event.

Comment: While I guess that you can manage on the hints Peter and I gave you alone, I think adding a code example for future reference can't hurt either..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `PictureBox` subclass that supports the ability to apply zooming not only to the `Image` but also to graphics you draw onto its surface.

It includes a `SetZoom` function to zoom in by scaling both itself and a Matrix.

It also has a `ScalePoint` function you can use to calculate the unscaled coordinates from the pixel coordinates you receive in the mouse events.

The idea is to use a `Transformation Matrix` to scale any pixels the `Graphics` object will draw in the `Paint` event.

I include a little code for the form for testing.

```
public partial class ScaledPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public Matrix ScaleM { get; set; }

    float Zoom { get; set; }
    Size ImgSize { get; set; }

    public ScaledPictureBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ScaleM = new Matrix();
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    }

    public void InitImage()
    {
        if (Image != null)
        {
            ImgSize = Image.Size;
            Size = ImgSize;
            SetZoom(100);
        }
    }

    public void SetZoom(float zoomfactor)
    {
        if (zoomfactor <= 0) throw new Exception("Zoom must be positive");
        float oldZoom = Zoom;
        Zoom = zoomfactor / 100f;
        ScaleM.Reset();
        ScaleM.Scale(Zoom , Zoom );
        if (ImgSize != Size.Empty) Size = new Size((int)(ImgSize.Width * Zoom), 
                                                   (int)(ImgSize.Height * Zoom));

    }

    public PointF ScalePoint(PointF pt)
    {   return new PointF(pt.X / Zoom , pt.Y / Zoom );     }

}
```

Here is the code in the Form that does the testing:

```
public List<PointF> somePoints = new List<PointF>();

private void scaledPictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    somePoints.Add(scaledPictureBox1.ScalePoint(e.Location) );
    scaledPictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void scaledPictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // here we apply the scaling matrix to the graphics object:
    e.Graphics.MultiplyTransform(scaledPictureBox1.ScaleM);
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10f))
    {
        PointF center = new PointF(scaledPictureBox1.Width / 2f, 
                                   scaledPictureBox1.Height / 2f);
        center = scaledPictureBox1.ScalePoint(center);
        foreach (PointF pt in somePoints)
        {
            DrawPoint(e.Graphics, pt, pen);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, center, pt);
        }
    }
}

public void DrawPoint(Graphics G, PointF pt, Pen pen)
{
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(pen.Color))
    {
        float pw = pen.Width;
        float pr = pw / 2f;
        G.FillEllipse(brush, new RectangleF(pt.X - pr, pt.Y - pr, pw, pw));
    }
}
```

Here are the results after drawing a few points showing the same points in four different zoom settings; the `ScaledPictureBox` is obviously placed in an `AutoScroll-Panel`. The lines show how to use the regular drawing commands..

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: thanks very much taw your hint was already enough :)
but thanks for all the effort to write the code and ofcourse it looks more efficient and organized..
unfortunately the person who gave me that task explicitly asked not to implement it using the transformations in C#.
i have figured out the problem with my code but i wont post my answer because i think yours is better.

Comment: Interesting. Without the transformation scaling the coordinates will work, too. There you also need to scale the Widths of Pens and then some..

Comment: An excellent answer that solved a long-standing problem for me (making a winforms designer to edit layouts). Thanks!