# Getting the mouse position on a zoomed picture

Tags: c#, bitmap, position, mouse, picturebox

I am creating a screenshot maker/uploader and everything works great but now i wanna intergrate something like paint. So first i am creating the pencil function. But there starts the problems i can draw :D but not on the position of my mouse. He takes other position then my cursor?

So the question is:
Hoe to get the mouse positions on a zoomed picturebox?

My code:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draw && pencil)
        {
            Graphics panel = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenShot);

            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 14);

            pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
            pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;

            panel.DrawLine(pen, pX, pY, e.X, e.Y);

            pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(ScreenShot, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
        Point p = pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

        pX = p.X;
        pY = p.Y;
    }
```

Comment: You need to do (at least) one of two things: a) calculate the points from the zoomed world to the unzoomed one and/or b) draw in a zoomed mode by scaling the graphics object you draw with. You can see both at work if you study [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633446/how-to-draw-on-zoomable-image-in-c-sharp-windows-forms/28645474#28645474). - For a) you also need to scale the pen width! (use float for all numbers as long as you can!!). BTW: No need to use PointToClient - use the e.Location etc parameters and divide them by the zoom factor!

Comment: And don't draw in the MouseMove, draw in the Paint event. In the MouseMove you store the coodinates of the points etc you draw in the paint event. And do not create a Graphics object until you know what you are doing, use the one in the Paint  e.Graphics param And do not name a Graphics object panel, you are funfusing everybody, most likely starting with yourself

Comment: collecting the points and then immediately converting them in a scalePoint function  is not really any extra work. Getting into the graphics model in GDI+ does have a certain learning curve but not really anything you need to worry about..

Comment: Thanks strange question but do you maybe have skype.

This is what i am making: http://playscripters.nl/topic/46

And i am busy with another update

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When using the mouse on a zoomed image the reported pixels are the zoomed coordinates. So we need to get at the real pixels..

After setting up things somehow..

```
float pbZoom = 3f;  // the factor by which the PictureBox is zoomed in or out

pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
pictureBox.ClientSize = new Size((int)(pictureBox.Image.Width * pbZoom),
         (int)(pictureBox.Image.Height * pbZoom));

pictureBox.Paint     += pictureBox_Paint;
pictureBox.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown;
pictureBox.MouseMove += pictureBox_MouseMove;
pictureBox.MouseUp   += pictureBox_MouseUp;
```

.. you can write the events to draw onto or into the zoomed image.

First a helper function to undo the zoom for a point:

```
PointF unZoomed(PointF pt) { return new PointF(pt.X / pbZoom, pt.Y / pbZoom );}
```

For simplicity lets keep a few things at class level:

```
PointF mDown    = PointF.Empty;   // mouse down point
PointF mCurrent = PointF.Empty;   // current mouse location
```

We start each mouse event by calculating the unzoomed `e.Location`.

Our test draws a straight, moving red line on the surface until you release the mouse. Then that line is drawn into the Image in green.

The `MouseDown` simply stores the starting point, unzoomed:

```
void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = unZoomed(e.Location);
}
```

In the `MouseMove` we store the current point and trigger the Paint event:

```
void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.None) return;

    PointF e_ = unZoomed(e.Location);
    mCurrent = e_;
    pictureBox.Invalidate();
}
```

In the `MouseUp` we draw the line into the `Image` of the `PictureBox`, changing its pixels; then we set the `Image` and reset the points:

```
void pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) pictureBox.Image;
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        G.DrawLine(Pens.Green, mDown, mCurrent);
     }
    mDown = PointF.Empty;
    mCurrent = PointF.Empty;
    pictureBox.Image = bmp;

}
```

To draw onto the Control surface we use the `Paint` event. To draw scaled we use a `Matrix`..:

```
void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.Scale(pbZoom, pbZoom);
    e.Graphics.MultiplyTransform(scaleMatrix);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, mDown, mCurrent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also working with zoom image. I simply use this code, it's working. So you can just compare with bitmap (original image) before zoomed in/out.

```
private void pbInput_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { 
    if (pbInput.Image == null) {
        mouseY.Text = "";
        mouseX.Text = "";
    }

    else {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pbInput.Image);
        int x = b.Width * e.X / pbInput.Width;
        int y = b.Height * e.Y / pbInput.Height;

        mouseX.Text = x.ToString();
        mouseY.Text = y.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);

            Size size1 = pictureBox1.Image.Size;
            Size size2 = pictureBox1.Size;


            float x1 = (float)size1.Width / ((float)size2.Width + 1);
            float y1 = (float)size1.Height / ((float)size2.Height + 1);

            float divisor = x1 >= y1 ? x1 : y1;

            divisor = divisor > 0 ? divisor : 1;

            Size imagesize = new Size((int)(size1.Width / divisor), (int)(size1.Height / divisor));
            int ex = imagesize.Width - size2.Width >= 0 ? imagesize.Width - size2.Width : size2.Width - imagesize.Width;
            int ey = imagesize.Height - size2.Height >= 0 ? imagesize.Height - size2.Height : size2.Height - imagesize.Height;



            float ftx = ((float)size1.Width / (float)imagesize.Width) * ((float)(Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X - pictureBox1.Location.X - (ex / 2) - 8));
            float fty = ((float)size1.Height / (float)imagesize.Height) * ((float)(Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y - pictureBox1.Location.Y - (ey / 2) - 31));

            Point LOP = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(ftx), Convert.ToInt32(fty)); //point of cursos on picturebox image pixel ...
```