# how to zoom drawing created on panel by mouse-wheel

Tags: c#

I want to apply zoom in-zoom out on drawing created on panel.I tried following code but problem is that zoom effect also applies on panel.
Below is my code snippet:

```
private void XY_dbleBufferPanel_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         // If the mouse wheel is moved forward (Zoom in)
         if (e.Delta > 0){
             if ((XY_dbleBufferPanel.Width < (15 * this.Width)) && (XY_dbleBufferPanel.Height < (15 * this.Height))){
                 XY_dbleBufferPanel.Width = (int)(XY_dbleBufferPanel.Width * 1.25);
                 XY_dbleBufferPanel.Height = (int)(XY_dbleBufferPanel.Height * 1.25);

                 XY_dbleBufferPanel.Top = (int)(e.Y - 1.25 * (e.Y - XY_dbleBufferPanel.Top));
                 XY_dbleBufferPanel.Left = (int)(e.X - 1.25 * (e.X - XY_dbleBufferPanel.Left));
             }
         }
         else{
             if ((XY_dbleBufferPanel.Width > (this.Width / 15)) && (XY_dbleBufferPanel.Height > (this.Height / 15))) {
                  XY_dbleBufferPanel.Width = (int)(XY_dbleBufferPanel.Width / 1.25);
                  XY_dbleBufferPanel.Height = (int)(XY_dbleBufferPanel.Height / 1.25);

                  XY_dbleBufferPanel.Top = (int)(e.Y - 0.80 * (e.Y - XY_dbleBufferPanel.Top));
                  XY_dbleBufferPanel.Left = (int)(e.X - 0.80 * (e.X - XY_dbleBufferPanel.Left));
                }
          }
}
```

Comment: I'd say it applies only to panel, since you are changing the size of the panel. The contents of the panel may or may not change size depending on the drawing code, controls etc. More information is needed to determine how you would only zoom them. If you draw them yourself, you have to pass the zoom factor to the drawing code. If they are other controls, it will be very complicated.

Comment: I draw shapes(like cube,cylinder) on panel.

Comment: The you just need to calculate the zoom factor in the mouse handling routine and pass that to the drawing code instead of changing the panel size. Of course you could use a panel inside a panel for clipping and making it without any other changes, but that would be an ugly kludge.

Comment: You change the size of a __picturebox__ to zoom its __image__. To zoom graphics __drawn__ on any control you __either__  resize all data needed for drawing __or__ you scale the `Graphics` object you use for drawing. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633446/how-to-draw-on-zoomable-image-in-c-sharp-windows-forms/28645474?s=5|0.2486#28645474) for an example of the latter!