# How put Image in ScrollViewer WPF

Tags: xaml

I try bind my Image size to slider, and put it to scroll viewer, but scroll viewer not working. I can't understand why.

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="1">
     <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Margin="2,2,2,2" Content="From file" Click="Button_Click"></Button> 
        <Button Margin="2,2,2,2"  Click="delImageClick" ToolTip="Delete">
           <Image Source="Resources/empty_trash-48.png"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Slider x:Name="sldZoom" Orientation="Horizontal" Minimum="1" Maximum="250" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" Value="100"/>
     </StackPanel>
     <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
       Image Name="previewImg" Source="{Binding SelectedItem,  ElementName=dataGrid , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0, 0" >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
         <TransformGroup>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.01" ScaleY="0.01"/>
             <ScaleTransform>
          <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>                                                     
             <Binding ElementName="sldZoom" Path="Value" Mode="OneWay"/>
          </ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
             <ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
                <Binding ElementName="sldZoom" Path="Value" Mode="OneWay"/>
             </ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
          </ScaleTransform>
          </TransformGroup>
          </Image.RenderTransform>
         </Image>
      </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
       </DockPanel>
```

Also I try put my Image into Dock and grid,It did not work either
[example on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbX4z.png)

Comment: You must define the size of the child element of the ScrollViewer, otherwise the control is unable to manage the scrollbars.

Comment: I set Height="250" Width="250" of Image properties, but it not working

Comment: what it means "not working"?

Comment: When I move slider my Image zoom in, but scrollviewer not activate scrollbar

Comment: The actual size of the ScrollViewer is probably greater than the Image's one. The scrollbar gets enabled when the child width/height is greater than the container. Try set the ScrollViewer width/height to 200x200, as for make an experiment.

Comment: Everything is as it was((no result

Comment: I solved my problem. Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I should be using LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform in my Image.
[WPF - Zooming in on an image inside a scroll viewer, and having the scrollbars adjust accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729853/wpf-zooming-in-on-an-image-inside-a-scroll-viewer-and-having-the-scrollbars-a)